# Box that seems to ignore the presence of the other

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a main app div on the website, and I divided it into two columns, one with 340px, and the other to use 100% of the available space, but instead of using the remaining space, this second div occupies the equivalent of the entire screen, as if the first part did not exist.

[image]

I'm pretty sure part of that is because the text within that second one is too big and doesn't wrap. but I wanted it to break and the second part was only on the screen, not off it.

you may need to resize the window to a smaller size to be able to see the error.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

img::selection {
  background: transparent;
}

body {
  background: #6D8DE0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.app-window {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.col1 {
  width: 340px;
}

.col2 {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.messagesContent {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.09);
}

.bottomOptions {
  background-color: #00000030;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.bottomOptions-text {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 36px;
  border-radius: 18px;
  margin: 12px 0px 12px 20px;
  background-color: #ffffff18;
}

.bottomOptions-text input {
  color: white;
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 0px 1px 0px 15px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

.bottomOptions-text input::placeholder {
  color: #ffffffB0;
}

.bottomOptions-text input::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #ffffffB0;
}

.bottomOptions-text input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #ffffffB0;
}

.bottomOptions-send {
  height: 30px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bottomOptions-send span {
  font-variation-settings: 'FILL' 1, 'wght' 700, 'GRAD' 200, 'opsz' 48;
  color: #ffffffB0;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.search {
  height: 43px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0px -2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.search .input {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 65%;
  border-color: #fff;
  padding: 6px 22x 6px 22px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border: 0.7px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition: 500ms;
}

.search .input:hover {
  width: 95%;
}

.search .input input {
  width: 100px;
  height: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #00000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  outline: 0;
  border-radius: 2px;
  transition: 500ms;
  text-align: center;
}

.search .input:hover input {
  width: 100%;
  background: #0000000e;
}

.search .input input::placeholder {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}

.boxAllMessages {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.boxAllMessages::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0px;
}

.allMessages {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.message:is(.my, .other) {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: min-content;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #00000000;
  color: white;
}

.message:is(.my, .other) p {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: keep-all;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.message.content {
  padding: 5px 40px 0 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

.message.content span {
  color: white;
}

.messageBox {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 0px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: start;
}

.senderPhoto {
  height: 45px;
  width: 45px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: 20px;
  align-self: flex-start;
  justify-self: start;
  transition: ease 200ms;
}

.senderPhoto:hover {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  transition: ease 200ms;
}
```

```html
<div class="app-window">
  <div class="col1">
    <div class="sideMenu" style="width: 340px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col2">
    <div class="messagesContent">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Sharp:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200">
      <div>
        <div class="search">
          <div class="input"><input placeholder="Seach"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="boxAllMessages">
        <div>
          <div class="allMessages">
            <div class="messageBox">
              <img class="senderPhoto" src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/brase-indev.appspot.com/o/profilePictures%2Fdefault.jpeg?alt=media&amp;token=74a37c10-c39d-483b-a129-9084e2e255e7">
              <div class="message content">
                <span><strong>Douglas</strong></span>
                <div class="message my">
                  <p>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="messageBox">
              <img class="senderPhoto" src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/brase-indev.appspot.com/o/profilePictures%2Fdefault.jpeg?alt=media&amp;token=74a37c10-c39d-483b-a129-9084e2e255e7">
              <div class="message content">
                <span><strong>Douglas</strong></span>
                <div class="message my">
                  <p>break break break break break break break break break break break break break break break break break break break break break break break break break break break break break break break break break break break break break break break
                    break break break break </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="messageBox">
              <img class="senderPhoto" src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/brase-indev.appspot.com/o/profilePictures%2Fdefault.jpeg?alt=media&amp;token=74a37c10-c39d-483b-a129-9084e2e255e7">
              <div class="message content">
                <span><strong>Douglas</strong></span>
                <div class="message my">
                  <p>break break break break break break break break break break break break break break break break break break break break break break break break break break break break break break break break break break break break break break break
                    break break break break break break break break break break break break break break </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="bottomOptions">
        <div class="bottomOptions-text"><input id="inputTextToSend" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Type something"></div>
        <div class="bottomOptions-send"><span class="material-symbols-sharp"> send </span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for adding more detail to your code. I cannot see the problem, in that the second column does seem to take up the remaining space. Could you describe what makes you conclude it has taken up much more? What I see is the overflowing text cut off. Did you want it to wrap?

Comment: if you resize the screen to something like width = 800px , you will see that column 2 will be cut off and if you check its size, you will see that it is equivalent to the total 800px instead of being in the remaining space. If there is no content inside, everything is normal, but the problem is that the text seems to "think" that it has more space than it actually has. It would be great if the text wraps correctly and the second column doesn't go off the screen

Answer (score 0):

I think I got what is your problem. Change the flex-direction property to row . This way div will be side by side and when the content inside exceeds the length of the div it will simply take new line.
Run the code snippet. If it is something different please comment down below what the issue is.

```css
body{
margin:0;
}
.app-window{
display: flex;
flex-direction:row;
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
}

.col1 {
background-color:red;
flex-direction:row;
width: 340px;
}

.col2 {
background-color:blue;
flex-direction:row;
width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<title>demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="app-window">
  <div class="col1">
  
  </div>
  <div class="col2">
  <p>
  jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj
  jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj
  jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj
  </p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`width: 100%` defines the width as a percentage of the containing block's width.

The containing block `.app-window` is `100vw` wide. So `.col2` would be the same (which is not what you want).

Instead, use `flex` to tell each `col` whether it can grow or shrink, and what it's `flex-basis` should be.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
}

.app-window {
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.col1 {
  flex: 0 0 340px;
  background: #6D8DE0;
}

.col2 {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background: #7A97E3;
}
```

```html
<div class="app-window">
  <div class='col1'>
  </div>
  <div class='col2'>

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas non aliquet justo. Vivamus gravida pulvinar ornare. Cras elementum euismod mauris, vitae lobortis tellus ultrices non. Cras aliquam luctus quam non hendrerit. Maecenas odio arcu, molestie id tristique sed, malesuada non nulla. Sed eget dui velit. Sed id condimentum orci. Phasellus.
  </div>
</div>
```